# Redux @computed with parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a table where each cell is by default shown in summary mode. When a user clicks on cell, the view within the cell is swapped with a detailed view. My first approach is to use a map and keep record of visible cells, like below.

```
visibleCells = observable.map({});
// toggles visibility
handleClick = (row: number, col: number) => {
        return action(() => this.visibleCells.set(`${row}-${col}`, !this.visibleCells.get(`${row}-${col}`)));
}
isCellExpanded = (row: number, col: number) => {
        return computed(() => this.visibleCells[`${row}-${co}`]);
}

getCell(row,col){
     return computed(() => this.visibleCells[`${row}-${col}`] && (<h1>...</h1>));
}

render(){
    ...
    {getCell(i,j)}; // not working
    ...
}
```

Q1. any idea how to fix the issue above?

Q2. Any alternative approach to keep state for each cell above?

Comment: What exactly error is?

Comment: no error, it is not working, there is no output produced from getCell(row,col) call. Trigger is changing state but getCell is not responding to redux changes.

Comment: have you try to dump ` this.visibleCells[`${row}-${col}`]`

Comment: try to see result tree builded in browser may be mentione statement always return false and nothig has added to tree

Comment: visibleCells variable is not showing up in the debug tool, basically the way I am using getCell above is wrong, it is not registering to mobx, any ideas

Comment: I suggest to modify code. Add the `cosole.log` statement to monitoring reuslt of all executions of mentioned statement. That allow to know exactly  its value.